# Preact Router doesn't render until async routes are resolved

Tags: javascript, html, css, preact, server-side-rendering

I have an app which is server side rendered, then rendered on the client to add functionality, however, although the time to first meaningful paint is around 1000ms, as soon as the client script downloads, the page turns white and after a few seconds it renders again (client).

After a bit of debugging I realized it was because I was doing this:

```
Preact.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

where app is:

```
import { Component } from 'preact';
import { Router } from 'preact-router';
import AsyncRoute from 'preact-async-route';

export default class App extends Component {
    handleRoute = e => {
        this.currentUrl = e.url;
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <div id="app">
                <Router onChange={ this.handleRoute }>
          <AsyncRoute path="/" getComponent={() => import('../routes/portfolio').then(module => module.default)} />
                </Router>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Now the problem is, the html is sent from the server, then rendered. But as soon as the client script is executed, the `<div id="app"></div>` is flushed because the `AsyncRoute` hasn't loaded yet, meaning there is nothing to render and so the page goes white. After the `AsyncRoute` loads, the `<div id="app"></div>` finally has content so the page is rerendered.

My question is, **how can I make it so that the router or app isn't rendered on the client (above) until all the dynamic imports are resolved?**

**NOTE: I can't simply do this:**

```
import(path).then(render)
```

Because when I add more components I won't be able to tell which paths to import, hence the `AsyncRoute` component

Answer (score 0):

The key here is to know which path are you serving and putting its bundle as `<script defer>` in the **head**, so by the time preact gets loaded (may be via a `script` tag in the bottom of the body), your path's JS gets loaded and your div doesn't go blank.

Or, in other words, the script which `loadComponent` will require is actually available in cache.

Comment: I am extremely sorry if it came across in that way.

Can you please share how did you do the SSR on `AsyncRoutes` because renderToString basically exits without fulfilling the promise of `require.ensure` or `System.import`

Comment: I render the stuff needed for the initial view, and lazy load the rest, which means I don't intend on loading it straight away so I can get a very fast first paint (time to interactive doesnt matter too much bc its a blot), then I lazy load the initial chunk (called main), which in turn lazy loads the other chunks needed for interactivity in the current view. Currently, using the preact-router module, means that once the initial chunk is loaded (lazily), the dom clears and the screen turns white, then after the other required chunks load (`import('chunk')`), the view repaints (after like 2s)

Comment: What I want is once the initial chunk is lazy loaded, I wait until all of the other chunks dynamically imported using `require` which are necessary for the current view before rerendering.

Comment: cool, i guess I got what you are saying.

So when you SSR you first see all the content then while `AsyncRoute` fetches the file the content goes blank while the file gets downloaded.

Comment: wrong answer, deleting it!

is that cool here @stackoverflow?

Comment: also: https://medium.com/@prateekbh/code-splitting-and-server-side-rendering-for-preact-async-routes-e8052e08ba22

Answer (score 0):

cool, i guess I got what you are saying.

So when you SSR you first see all the content then while `AsyncRoute` fetches the file the content goes blank while the file gets downloaded.

Is it right?

In this case I made you a simple demo: https://github.com/prateekbh/preact-async-ssr

The solution is not very clean(also wasn't able to find any clean solutions so far even in React land), but here's what I did:

**Before removing the SSRed markup I save it in a variable and then use it as a loader component in AsyncRoute. Details here: https://github.com/prateekbh/preact-async-ssr/blob/master/client-routes/App/app.js#L25-L39**

Let me know if this helps.